# Firebase mail verify

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I just want to make a verify screen and it will close when any user clicks the submitted verify link by Firebase. Should I add a future function for that?

```
if (!user.emailVerified){
  user.sendEmailVerification();
  Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VerifyScreen(),),);
}
```

What should I add to this code?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go about, and it depends on the behavior you want to have. If I understand you correctly, I would probably create a Cubit that subscribes to userChanges(), and on the VerifyScreen() page have a BlocListener that redirects the user away from that screen when the user has verified the email via the link.

### PseudoCode

Part in Cubit:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user) {
  if (user.emailVerified) {
    emit(UserEmailVerificationState.verified());
  }
});
```

Part in VerifyScreen():

```
      BlocListener<UserEmailVerificationCubit, UserEmailVerificationState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          state.maybeMap(
              verified: (_) {
                ExtendedNavigator.of(context).replace(Routes.secretPage);
              },
              orElse: () {});
        },
      ),
```